# Margin paragraph alignment if using \sloppy

Tags: wrapfigure, marginnote

Please see my MWE. I would like the \marginnote paragraph to be aligned with the point in which I invoke it. In the inner margin I have a wrap figure environment that contains text very big (46pt). If I don't use \sloppy, text of margin paragraph and of main paragraph overlap. If I use \sloppy, I run into problems with alignment. Please, what am I doing wrong? Thanks.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{marginnote}
 \renewcommand*{\marginfont}{\scriptsize \sffamily}
   \renewcommand\raggedrightmarginnote{}
\renewcommand\raggedleftmarginnote{}


\usepackage[
paperwidth=160mm, paperheight=240mm,
textheight=18cm,
textwidth=8cm,
inner=2cm, marginparwidth=2.5cm, marginparsep=0.5cm]
    {geometry}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
%\sloppy


\newpage

\paragraph{First}
\begin{wrapfigure}{i}{0.64\textwidth}%
  \vspace{5pt}
  \noindent  {\fontsize{46pt}{46pt}\selectfont \hspace{-5pt}  Big}
  \end{wrapfigure}
This\marginnote{I want this to be aligned. \lipsum[1]} is a paragraph. \lipsum[1]

\newpage

\paragraph{First}
\begin{wrapfigure}{i}{0.64\textwidth}%
  \vspace{5pt}
  \noindent  {\fontsize{46pt}{46pt}\selectfont \hspace{-5pt}  Big}
  \end{wrapfigure}
This\marginnote{I want this to be aligned. \lipsum[1]} is a paragraph. \lipsum[1]

\newpage
\paragraph{Forth}
\begin{wrapfigure}{i}{0.64\textwidth}%
  \vspace{5pt}
  \noindent  {\fontsize{46pt}{46pt}\selectfont \hspace{-5pt}  Big}
  \end{wrapfigure}
This\marginnote{I want this to be aligned. \lipsum[1]} is a paragraph. \lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: When I compile it (yes, with xelatex) in page 3 the paragraph at the margin shift one line down.

Comment: I see that if I place the \marginnote immediately after the \paragraph, it gets solved. But in my real world text I'm running into a lot of misalignment issues that I'm not able to correct... So I don't know if you can see something in my setup that could bring to problems?

Comment: It appears that the margin note is being aligned to "is" instead of "This".  If you place a `~` between the two, "is" gets moved up to the same line as "This".  The difference is due to "Fourth" vs. "First".

Comment: Plcing the margin nute in front of "This" instead of after works.

Comment: Yes you are right. Then it means that I have to solve problem by problem in my book... But you are confirming that the way I'm using \wrapfigure together with \marginnote is fine? Thanks

Comment: Wrapfigure doesn;t really change the text (except for the margins).  Now a marginnote inside the wrapfigure would be another problem altogether.

Comment: Understood thanks

Comment: Please see this related question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/694149/page-number-alignment-when-using-marginnote