# Layout of main text with comment at the margins (talmud layout)

Tags: marginnote, changepage, talmud

Please see the MWE. Page 1 shows a text with a comment at the margin that is only a few lines. What I want is that the main text expands underneath the marginal comment. In page 2 we have the opposite situation. In this case it is the main text that is short and the marginal note that should expand underneath it. I kept the MWE minimal, but I'm adding a picture to show the layout I wish to obtain. I tried to obtain this by using the packages marginnote and change page. The hebrew character has been added to the main text with the \wrapfigure environment. There is also the possibility of having, instead of the heading in my example, an inner marginal comment. At the end, I'm aiming to a layout that resemble the classical Vilna Talmud layout (See [https://www.sas.upenn.edu/~jtreat/rs/002/Judaism/talmud.html](https://www.sas.upenn.edu/%7Ejtreat/rs/002/Judaism/talmud.html)).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{marginnote}
 \renewcommand*{\marginfont}{\scriptsize }
   \renewcommand\raggedrightmarginnote{}
\renewcommand\raggedleftmarginnote{}

\usepackage[
paperwidth=160mm, paperheight=240mm,
textheight=18cm,
textwidth=7.5cm,
inner=2cm, 
marginparwidth=2.5cm, marginparsep=0.5cm,
showframe]
    {geometry}
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\begin{document}
\sloppy

\paragraph*{First}
This
\marginnote{This is a small margin paragraph, way smaller that the text it comments.}
is a long text, way longer that the comment at its margin. So there is no need to keep the paragraph width as is but it can be expanded by 3 cm.
\begin{adjustwidth*}{}{-3cm}
 \lipsum[1]
 \end{adjustwidth*}

\newpage
\paragraph{First}
This
\marginnote{This is a long margin note. The text is small so the margin note can expand and take over all the space in the page. \lipsum[1]}
is a small paragraph that lasts only a few lines.
\end{document}
```

[image: To show you the layout I wish to obtain]

Comment: Its not fully clear to me what you want to do with the margin. If you want to increase it permanently, just try changing the `marginparwidth=` in your `geometry` options. But what do you mean by towards the inner part? Seen from the margin, the inner part is where the text area is. Expanding in this direction has to shrink the text area, as long as you don't decrease the `inner` option or the `marginparsep`.

Comment: Maybe draw a short sketch showing, what you want to achieve. And use `showframe` option with `geometry`, so you can see the borders of your margin etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use some do some arithmetic to calculate the number of lines needs to indent for the shorter (by height) text, then use `\hangindent` and `\hangafter` to typeset the longer text, and add the shorter one in a box:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[
paperwidth=160mm, paperheight=240mm,
textheight=18cm,
textwidth=10.5cm,
inner=2cm, 
showframe]
    {geometry}
 
\def\divtrancate(#1/#2){%
    \ifnum\numexpr #1 - #2*\numexpr #1/#2\relax<0
    \the\numexpr #1/#2\relax\else\the\numexpr #1/#2+1\relax\fi
}

 
\newbox\mishna
\newbox\tosafot
\def\talmudlayout#1 #2\par#3\par{
\setbox\mishna\vbox{\hsize=7.5cm\relax\noindent\textbf{#1}.\hskip 1em\relax #2}
\setbox\tosafot\vbox{\hsize=2.5cm\relax\scriptsize\noindent #3\par}
\ifdim\ht\mishna>\ht\tosafot
    \hangafter=-\divtrancate(\dimexpr\ht\tosafot\relax/\dimexpr\baselineskip\relax)
    \hangindent=-3cm
    \noindent
    \vadjust{\moveright 8cm\vbox to 0pt{\vskip-.5\baselineskip\box\tosafot\vss}}%
    \textbf{#1}.\hskip 1em\relax #2\par
\else
    \hangafter=-\divtrancate(\dimexpr\ht\mishna\relax/\dimexpr 9.5pt\relax)
    \hangindent=8cm
    \noindent
    \vadjust{\vbox to 0pt{\vskip-.5\baselineskip\box\mishna\vss}}%
    {\scriptsize #3\par}
\fi
}
    
\begin{document}

\talmudlayout First
This is a long text, way longer than the comment at its margin.
So there is no need to keep the paragraph width as is but it can 
be expanded by 3 cm. \lipsum[1]

This is a small margin paragraph, way smaller than the text it comments.

\newpage
\talmudlayout Second
This is a short text, way shorter than the comment at its margin.
So there is no need to keep the comment width as is but it can 
be expanded by 8 cm.

This is a long margin paragraph, way longer than the text it comments.
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

If you want to change the side of the comment depending on the page number, just like \marginnote, simply add another test in the macro:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[
paperwidth=160mm, paperheight=240mm,
textheight=18cm,
textwidth=10.5cm,
inner=2cm, 
showframe]
    {geometry}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\writetalmudpage{%
\write\@auxout{%
    \string\expandafter\gdef\string\csname\space talmudlayout@\thetalmudpage\string\endcsname{\thepage}}}
\makeatother

\newcommand*\defloop[1]{%
    \expandafter\def\csname talmudlayout@#1\endcsname{0}
    \ifnum#1<100
    \expandafter\defloop
    \expandafter{\number\numexpr#1+1\expandafter}%
    \fi}
\defloop{1}
 
\def\divtrancate(#1/#2){%
    \ifnum\numexpr #1 - #2*\numexpr #1/#2\relax<0
    \the\numexpr #1/#2\relax\else\the\numexpr #1/#2+1\relax\fi
}

\newcounter{talmudpage}
\newbox\mishna
\newbox\tosafot
\def\talmudlayout#1 #2\par#3\par{
\stepcounter{talmudpage}
\setbox\mishna\vbox{\hsize=7.5cm\relax\noindent\textbf{#1}.\hskip 1em\relax #2}
\setbox\tosafot\vbox{\hsize=2.5cm\relax\scriptsize\noindent #3\par}
\ifdim\ht\mishna>\ht\tosafot
    \hangafter=-\divtrancate(\dimexpr\ht\tosafot\relax/\dimexpr\baselineskip\relax)
    \hangindent=\ifodd\csname talmudlayout@\thetalmudpage\endcsname -3cm\else 3cm\fi
    \noindent\writetalmudpage
    \vadjust{\ifodd\csname talmudlayout@\thetalmudpage\endcsname \moveright 8cm\fi\vbox to 0pt{\vskip-.5\baselineskip\box\tosafot\vss}}%
    \textbf{#1}.\hskip 1em\relax #2\par
\else
    \hangafter=-\divtrancate(\dimexpr\ht\mishna\relax/\dimexpr 9.5pt\relax)
    \ifodd\csname talmudlayout@\thetalmudpage\endcsname \hangindent=8cm\else \hangindent=-8cm\fi 
    \noindent\writetalmudpage
    \vadjust{\ifodd\csname talmudlayout@\thetalmudpage\endcsname\else \moveright 3cm\fi\vbox to 0pt{\vskip-.5\baselineskip\box\mishna\vss}}%
    {\scriptsize #3\par}
\fi
}
    
\begin{document}
\sloppy
\talmudlayout First
This is a long text, way longer than the comment at its margin.
So there is no need to keep the paragraph width as is but it can 
be expanded by 3 cm. \lipsum[1]

This is a small margin paragraph, way smaller than the text it comments.

\newpage
\talmudlayout Second
This is a long text, way longer than the comment at its margin.
So there is no need to keep the paragraph width as is but it can 
be expanded by 3 cm. \lipsum[1]

This is a small margin paragraph, way smaller than the text it comments.

\newpage
\talmudlayout Third
This is a short text, way shorter than the comment at its margin.
So there is no need to keep the comment width as is but it can 
be expanded by 8 cm.

This is a long margin paragraph, way longer than the text it comments.
\lipsum[1]

\newpage
\talmudlayout Fourth
This is a short text, way shorter than the comment at its margin.
So there is no need to keep the comment width as is but it can 
be expanded by 8 cm.

This is a long margin paragraph, way longer than the text it comments.
\lipsum[1]


\end{document}
```

## Edit

The second block of code had some issues, so I fixed it. It now need two compilations to get the correct results.

As for the questions in the comments, I think making a package would be the easiest thing to do here.

Put the following code in a file called `talmudlayout.sty`:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{talmudlayout}

\RequirePackage{xkeyval}
\RequirePackage{footnote}
\newlength\talmudlayout@mishna@width
\setlength\talmudlayout@mishna@width{.7\textwidth}
\newlength\talmudlayout@tosafot@width
\setlength\talmudlayout@tosafot@width{.25\textwidth}
\newlength\talmudlayout@mishnahead@hsep
\setlength\talmudlayout@mishnahead@hsep{.05\textwidth}
\newcommand*\talmudlayout@tosafot@size{scriptsize}
\newcommand*\talmudlayout@mishna@ext{0}
\newcommand*\talmudlayout@tosafot@ext{0}
\newcommand*\talmudlayout@mishnahead@ext{0}
\newcommand*\talmudlayout@max{30}

\DeclareOptionX{tosafot}{\renewcommand*\talmudlayout@tosafot@ext{#1}}
\DeclareOptionX{mishna}{\renewcommand*\talmudlayout@mishna@ext{#1}}
\DeclareOptionX{head}{\renewcommand*\talmudlayout@mishnahead@ext{#1}}
\DeclareOptionX{max}{\talmudlayout@max}
\DeclareOptionX{headsep}{\setlength\talmudlayout@mishnahead@hsep{#1}}
\DeclareOptionX{mishnawidth}{\setlength\talmudlayout@mishna@width{#1}}
\DeclareOptionX{tosafotwidth}{\setlength\talmudlayout@tosafot@width{#1}}
\DeclareOptionX{tosafotsize}{\renewcommand*\talmudlayout@tosafot@size{#1}}
\ProcessOptionsX\relax



\newif\if@talmudlyaout@headmax

\newcommand*\talmudlayout@savecounters{%
    \begingroup
    \def\@elt##1{%
    \global\csname c@##1\endcsname\the\csname c@##1\endcsname}%
    \xdef\@gtempa{%
        \cl@@ckpt
        \let\noexpand\talmudlayout@restorecounters\noexpand\@empty
    }%
    \endgroup
    \let\talmudlayout@restorecounters\@gtempa
}
\newcommand*\talmudlayout@restorecounters{}
\let\talmudlayout@restorecounters\@empty

\newcommand*\talmudlayout@skip{}
{\csname \talmudlayout@tosafot@size\endcsname\xdef\talmudlayout@skip{\the\baselineskip}}

\newcommand*\write@talmudlayout@page{%
\write\@auxout{%
    \string\expandafter\gdef\string\csname\space talmudlayout@\thetalmudlayout@page\string\endcsname{\thepage}}}

\newcommand*\talmudlayout@defloop[1]{%
    \expandafter\def\csname talmudlayout@#1\endcsname{0}
    \ifnum#1<\talmudlayout@max
    \expandafter\talmudlayout@defloop
    \expandafter{\number\numexpr#1+1\expandafter}%
    \fi}
\talmudlayout@defloop{1}

\newcommand*\talmudlayout@exploop[3]{% #1 = start, #2 = max, #3 = min
    \ifnum #1<\numexpr #3+1\relax
        \ifodd\csname talmudlayout@\thetalmudlayout@page\endcsname
            \dimexpr \wd\talmudlayout@mishnaheadh + \talmudlayout@mishnahead@hsep\relax 
            \dimexpr \talmudlayout@mishna@width - \wd\talmudlayout@mishnaheadh-\talmudlayout@mishnahead@hsep\relax
        \else
            \dimexpr \textwidth-\talmudlayout@mishna@width \relax 
            \dimexpr \talmudlayout@mishna@width - \wd\talmudlayout@mishnaheadh-\talmudlayout@mishnahead@hsep\relax
    \fi
    \else
        \if@talmudlyaout@headmax
            \ifodd\csname talmudlayout@\thetalmudlayout@page\endcsname
            \dimexpr \wd\talmudlayout@mishnaheadh+\talmudlayout@mishnahead@hsep\relax 
            \dimexpr \textwidth-\wd\talmudlayout@mishnaheadh-\talmudlayout@mishnahead@hsep\relax
        \else
            \z@ \dimexpr\textwidth-\wd\talmudlayout@mishnaheadh-\talmudlayout@mishnahead@hsep\relax
        \fi
    \else
        \ifodd\csname talmudlayout@\thetalmudlayout@page\endcsname
            \z@ \dimexpr\talmudlayout@mishna@width\relax
        \else
            \dimexpr \textwidth-\talmudlayout@mishna@width \relax \talmudlayout@mishna@width
        \fi
    \fi
    \fi
    \ifnum#1<#2
    \expandafter\talmudlayout@exploop
    \expandafter{\the\numexpr#1+1\expandafter}%
    \expandafter{\the\numexpr#2\expandafter}%
    \expandafter{\the\numexpr#3\expandafter}%
    \fi}

\newcommand*\talmudlayout@divtrancate[2]{%
    \ifnum\numexpr #1 - #2*\numexpr #1/#2\relax<0
    \the\numexpr #1/#2\relax\else\the\numexpr #1/#2+1\relax\fi
}

\newcommand*\talmudlayout@parshape[2]{
    \ifnum #1 <  #2 
            \@talmudlyaout@headmaxtrue
        \parshape \numexpr #2+1\relax
        \talmudlayout@exploop{1}{#2}{#1}
    \else
           \@talmudlyaout@headmaxfalse
       \parshape \numexpr #1+1\relax
       \talmudlayout@exploop{1}{#1}{#2}
    \fi
    \z@ \textwidth    
}

\def\talmudlayout@mishna@box#1#2#3{\vbox{\hsize=\talmudlayout@mishna@width
    \hangafter=-\numexpr\talmudlayout@divtrancate{\dimexpr\ht\talmudlayout@mishnaheadv\relax}{\dimexpr \baselineskip\relax}+\talmudlayout@mishnahead@ext\relax
    \ifodd\csname talmudlayout@\thetalmudlayout@page\endcsname
        \hangindent=\dimexpr \wd\talmudlayout@mishnaheadh + \talmudlayout@mishnahead@hsep\relax
    \else
    \hangindent=-\dimexpr \wd\talmudlayout@mishnaheadh + \talmudlayout@mishnahead@hsep\relax
    \fi
    \noindent
    \vadjust{\ifodd\csname talmudlayout@\thetalmudlayout@page\endcsname\else \moveright \dimexpr \talmudlayout@mishna@width - \wd\talmudlayout@mishnaheadh\relax\fi
        \vbox to 0pt{\vskip-.75\baselineskip\bfseries\fontsize{46pt}{46pt}\selectfont\noindent #1\vss}}%
    \strut\textbf{#2}.\hskip 1em\relax #3}}


\newbox\talmudlayout@mishnaheadh
\newbox\talmudlayout@mishnaheadv
\newbox\talmudlayout@mishna
\newbox\talmudlayout@tosafot
\newcounter{talmudlayout@page}
\newcommand*\talmudlayout{}
\long\protected\def\talmudlayout#1 #2 #3\par#4\par{
\stepcounter{talmudlayout@page}
\talmudlayout@savecounters
\setbox\talmudlayout@mishnaheadh\hbox{\bfseries\fontsize{46pt}{46pt}\selectfont\noindent #1}
\talmudlayout@restorecounters\talmudlayout@savecounters
\setbox\talmudlayout@mishnaheadv\vbox{\bfseries\fontsize{46pt}{46pt}\selectfont\noindent #1}
\talmudlayout@restorecounters\talmudlayout@savecounters
\setbox\talmudlayout@mishna\talmudlayout@mishna@box{#1}{#2}{#3}
\talmudlayout@restorecounters\talmudlayout@savecounters
\setbox\talmudlayout@tosafot\vbox{\hsize=\talmudlayout@tosafot@width\csname \talmudlayout@tosafot@size\endcsname\noindent\strut #4\par}
\talmudlayout@restorecounters\savenotes
\ifdim\ht\talmudlayout@mishna>\ht\talmudlayout@tosafot
    \talmudlayout@parshape{\numexpr\talmudlayout@divtrancate{\dimexpr\ht\talmudlayout@tosafot\relax}{\dimexpr \baselineskip\relax}+\talmudlayout@mishna@ext\relax}%
        {\numexpr\talmudlayout@divtrancate{\dimexpr\ht\talmudlayout@mishnaheadv\relax}{\dimexpr \baselineskip\relax}+\talmudlayout@mishnahead@ext\relax}
    \noindent\write@talmudlayout@page
    \vadjust{\ifodd\csname talmudlayout@\thetalmudlayout@page\endcsname \moveright \dimexpr\textwidth-\talmudlayout@tosafot@width\relax\fi
        \vbox to 0pt{\vskip-.75\baselineskip\vbox{\hsize=\talmudlayout@tosafot@width\csname \talmudlayout@tosafot@size\endcsname\noindent\strut #4\par}\vss}}%
    \vadjust{\ifodd\csname talmudlayout@\thetalmudlayout@page\endcsname\else \moveright \dimexpr\textwidth-\wd\talmudlayout@mishnaheadh\relax\fi
        \vbox to 0pt{\vskip-.75\baselineskip\bfseries\fontsize{46pt}{46pt}\selectfont\noindent #1\vss}}%
    \strut\textbf{#2}.\hskip 1em\relax #3\par
\else
    \hangafter=-\numexpr\talmudlayout@divtrancate{\dimexpr\ht\talmudlayout@mishna\relax}{\dimexpr \talmudlayout@skip\relax}+\talmudlayout@tosafot@ext\relax
    \ifodd\csname talmudlayout@\thetalmudlayout@page\endcsname
        \hangindent=\dimexpr\textwidth-\talmudlayout@tosafot@width
    \else
        \hangindent=-\dimexpr\textwidth-\talmudlayout@tosafot@width
    \fi
    \noindent\write@talmudlayout@page
    \vadjust{\ifodd\csname talmudlayout@\thetalmudlayout@page\endcsname\else \moveright \dimexpr\textwidth-\talmudlayout@mishna@width\relax\fi
        \vbox to 0pt{\vskip-\talmudlayout@skip\talmudlayout@mishna@box{#1}{#2}{#3}\vss}}%
    {\csname \talmudlayout@tosafot@size\endcsname\strut #4\par}
\fi
\par
\spewnotes
}
\endinput
```

Now I think you want something similar to the following document

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[
paperwidth=160mm, paperheight=240mm,
textheight=18cm,
textwidth=10.5cm,
inner=2cm]
    {geometry}

\usepackage[
tosafot=1,
mishna=1,
head=1,
headsep=1cm,
mishnawidth=7.5cm,
tosafotwidth=2.5cm]
{talmudlayout}

\begin{document}
\sloppy
\talmudlayout Big First
This is a long text, way longer than the comment at its margin.
So there is no need to keep the paragraph width as is but it can 
be expanded by 3 cm. \lipsum[1]

This is a small margin paragraph, way smaller than the text it comments.

\newpage
\talmudlayout Big Second
This is a long text, way longer than the comment at its margin.
So there is no need to keep the paragraph width as is but it can 
be expanded by 3 cm. \lipsum[1]

This is a small margin paragraph, way smaller than the text it comments.

\newpage
\talmudlayout Big Third
This is a short text, way shorter than the comment at its margin.
So there is no need to keep the comment width as is but it can 
be expanded by 8 cm.

This is a long margin paragraph, way longer than the text it comments.
\lipsum[1]

\newpage
\talmudlayout Big Fourth
This is a short text, way shorter than the comment at its margin.
So there is no need to keep the comment width as is but it can 
be expanded by 8 cm.

This is a long margin paragraph, way longer than the text it comments.
\lipsum[1]


\end{document}
```

The package defines a macro called `\talmudlayout` which accept 4 arguments.

- The first is the head of the main text, and is delimited by space after it.
- The second is the first word of the main text and is delimited by a space.
- The third is the main text, and it is delimited by `\par` so if you will want several paragraphs in this argument, you will have to use `\endgraf`, or change the delimiters of the arguments.
- The fourth is the margin text and it is also delimited by \par, same remarks apply to him.

Feel free to change the delimiters if you find the syntax inconvenient.

The package has 8 options.

- `tosafot`, `head` and `mishna` adds extra lines of space below the specified part (the default is 0).
- `mishnawidth` and `tosafotwidth` controls the width of the main and "margin" text (at least when they overlap, defaults are `.7\textwidth` and `.25\textwidth`).
- `headsep` is the horizontal space between the head and the main text (default is `.05\textwidth`).
- `max` is the maximum allowed of layouts in a document (default is `30`)
- `tosafotsize` is a name of a command size to control the size of the margin text (default is `scriptsize`).

This code will need two compilations as well. Feel free to change the default values of the options, I did not put much thought about them.

For a better alignment of the first lines you will need to tweak some of the length I used in the code,  probably tweaking the length of the `\vskip` will eventually get you what you want.

The example file presents the four possible situation of the layout.

- The main text is longer then the margin text, and the page number is odd
  [image]
- The main text is longer then the margin text, and the page number is even
  [image]
- The main text is shorter then the margin text, and the page number is odd
  [image]
- The main text is shorter then the margin text, and the page number is even
  [image]

Comment: Thanks Udi this is exactly what I needed! It works and it permits me to have a neat readable text separated from the code. Unfortunately my latex knowledge is little. I understand the logic of your code but not all commands. So maybe you can help me with a couple of tweaks.

Comment: 1. How do I add vertical spacing between the two blocks of text?

Comment: 2. How do I force perfect alignment of first line of both texts? With \strut?

Comment: Another couple of questions:

Comment: 1. If I use \sloppy (which I have to have justification of the marginal paragraphs) then the vertical alignment needs to be redefined.

Comment: 2. Please see my other question where you can see that in my final layout I also have an inner block of text, that until now I was trying to set up with the \wrapfigure environment (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/694149/page-number-alignment-when-using-marginnote/694203?noredirect=1#comment1723080_694203). But I cannot add \wrapfigure to your code.

Comment: And thanks for adding the example with the margin note always on the outer margin, this is what I need.

Comment: I added a picture to show how I used the wrapfigure environment to obtain the inner column.

Comment: @Haim See my Edit.

Comment: @Haim I guess it also solves your problem [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/694149/264024)

Comment: Udi, this is amazing thanks! You solved a problem I've been struggling for a while! Just to let you know, I typeset a book with a similar layout, and I used paracol. It worked but I had to add paragraphs' break manually, which is a pain...

Comment: Only one detail: I meant the 'Head' text, the 'Big" to be always on the inner part of a page, like Rashi in the talmud. How could I tweak your style to do this?

Comment: Also: Can I add foot and margin notes to the texts?

Comment: And finally: probably the title of my question should change to reflect your solution. There are a few of talmud layout threads and I think a few people would find your solution of great help. Do you have a suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: @Haim I see, so the head text should always be opposite to the margin text?  As for margin notes, just use `\marginnote` from the `marginnote` package, not `\marginpar`. I don't currently remember what to do with footnotes inside boxes, I'm sure there are answers in this site.

Comment: Do note that as long as the footnote is not inside a box, i.e. not a part of the shorter text, you'll be ok.

Comment: I cannot try your edited answer now. In the previous, the footnote worked but the counter was starting at 2.

Comment: @Haim I'm not sure what do you mean by "cannot try", does the code not compile? or just the footnote does not get displayed?

Comment: @Haim Please see the second edit. I think it works now with footnotes, and the head text is on the side you want.

Comment: 'Cannot try' just meant I had not time at that moment. I compiled now and it works beautifully.

Comment: Unfortunately the footnotes still give me a problem: no issue with footnotes to the short text (Mishnah or tosafot) but footnotes to the long text are doubled. If I add a footnote with the command \footnote{}; I obtain two footnotes with the same content (numbered say 1 and 2) and one marker (2 in this case).

Comment: @Haim, please try again (it is not perfect, when I'll have time I'll clean the code a bit).

Comment: It works perfectly thanks! (It also works with the marginnote package.

Comment: A few more tweaks and this could become a very useful package. For example the `head' in my layout could become a real inner margin note, of expandable width, like 'tosafot'. Or there could be a way to accomodate pages where there are no margin notes or only on one side. I'm available to help you with questions and testing and writing of documentation if you like. Unfortunately cannot help with the tex coding.

Comment: I don't think there is a package for talmud layout yet, only some attempts like this one: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141924/how-to-typeset-a-complex-layout-like-a-page-of-the-talmud

Comment: @Haim, well, I won't have much time in the following couple of weeks, but if tou will send an email with all the details, and all the possible cases of the layout (odd/even pages, mishna is longest, tosafot is longest, main text is longest etc.), I believe i could add more functionality in three weeks or so...

Comment: Will do! Thanks so much Udi!

Answer (score 0):

Since your wanted output is not totally clear, I just guessed something from your question. Maybe is that the style you're looking for (Doesn't necessary is the best way to do it, but uses your MWE as basis):

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{marginnote}
 \renewcommand*{\marginfont}{\scriptsize }
   \renewcommand\raggedrightmarginnote{}
\renewcommand\raggedleftmarginnote{}

\usepackage[fontsize=13pt]{fontsize}
\usepackage[
paperwidth=160mm, 
paperheight=240mm,
textheight=18cm,
textwidth=7.5cm,
inner=2cm, 
marginparwidth=5cm, 
marginparsep=0.5cm,
showframe]
{geometry}
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}
\begin{document}
\sloppy

\paragraph{First}
\marginnote{%
    \begin{adjustwidth*}{2.5cm}{}
    This is a long margin note that takes over the whole page. 
    \end{adjustwidth*}
    \lipsum[1]
    }{} is a small paragraph that lasts only a few lines.
\end{document}
```

Looks like this:

[image: first version]

Or did you indeed want to shrink the `inner` margin and the `marginparsep` so the text area can move further inwards and the enlarged `marginnote` is closer to the middle of the text:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{marginnote}
 \renewcommand*{\marginfont}{\scriptsize }
   \renewcommand\raggedrightmarginnote{}
\renewcommand\raggedleftmarginnote{}

\usepackage[fontsize=13pt]{fontsize}
\usepackage[
paperwidth=160mm, 
paperheight=240mm,
textheight=18cm,
textwidth=7.5cm,
inner=.5cm, 
marginparwidth=2.5cm, 
marginparsep=0.1cm,
showframe]
{geometry}
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}
\begin{document}
\sloppy

\paragraph{First}
\marginnote{This is a long margin note that takes over the all page. 
     \begin{adjustwidth*}{}{-8em} \lipsum[1]
     \end{adjustwidth*}
     }{} is a small paragraph that lasts only a few lines.
\end{document}
```

Looks like that (but really arkward, IMHO):

[image: second version]

**Or** something totally different, which I could not guess from your question... ;)

Comment: Thanks. My fault I was not clear, apologies. I tried to update my question and MWE. Please tell me if it is clear now.

Comment: For a background of what I'm after, please see the typical talmud layout, where the margin notes expand inward when the text is short, and viceversa. http://murals.wbtla.org/uploads/2/4/7/9/24790045/talmud_layout_%281%29.pdf

Comment: OK, now I get an idea oft what you want. But, to be honest, I see no straightforward way to accomplish that. For your demands you need to adjust `textwidth`, `marginparwidth` etc. in the middle of a paragraph and that multiple times on the same page. AFAIK there are no boxes in Latex which have uneven widths or change them while not leaving the "box-environment". Maybe there is a way to automatically widen the `left/rightmargin` of the `marginpar` when the `left/rightmargin` of the text is shrinked to overlap in the other area and vice versa. But my TeX knowledge isn't deep enough for that...

Comment: I guess in that case you need the knowledge of one of the longtime TeX/LaTeX pros on this webpage. Sorry and good luck ;)